# Where to place files in iib

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I'm using IIB v10.0.0.18 and I'm trying to read a file placed in a project uses JavaCompute node where project structure is like below

[image]

I'm trying to do below

```
File schemaFile = new File("schema.json");
```

but when I use this schemaFile, I'm getting FileNotFound exception.
Any idea where should I place the file should that it can be found by IIB ?

Comment: Question 1: Why is your Java in the same project as your message flow? I strongly advise against this approach. You should create a separate IIB shared library to contain your Java classes, and add a reference to that _shared library_ in each project that needs to do JSON validation.

Comment: Question 2: Have you deployed this code? If so, look in the IIB runtime directories to see where the file 'schema.json' has been deployed.

Comment: I added the Java class in a shared library as suggested by you and referred to this lib. in my project.
For the second question, what do you mean by IIB runtime directories ?

Comment: IIB files are deployed into a set of directories on the server. The root directory is in environment variable MQSI_WORKPATH. I would expect all of the contents of the BAR file to end up somewhere under that directory. However...it is possible that the JSON schema file will not be deployed at all because it is not an IIB native file. You may need to create a config directory and explicitly point your Java code at that directory.